# When installing setuptools on Debian Lenny, why do I get zlib error?

Tags: python, debian-lenny, setuptools

I'm seeing this error when I run `python2.6 setup.py build` on Debian Lenny from the `setuptools-0.6c11` source:

```
Compression requires the (missing) zlib module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the problem is that python2.6 was not build with zlib. I ran the following commands and this fixed my problem (this assumes you have the Python 2.6 source):

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
cd Python-2.6.5
./configure
make
make install
```

... there are also lots of other things that python will build with. The installer will not fail if they're missing, it'll just build without them.